# Digital sign of PDF with PAdES standard

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I need to sign a pdf document with PADES standard.

I'm programming with c#.

Somebody can suggest something ?

Best regards

Piercarlo

Answer (score 3):

You can try [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). Although I still haven't tried myself, it supports signing files using the PAdES standard. [Here's a sample](http://itextpdf.sourceforge.net/howtosign.html#ltvitext), and [here's another](http://bouncy-castle.1462172.n4.nabble.com/How-sign-a-Pdf-with-Pades-standard-td3717892.html).

Mind you, the latest version is dual licensed, Affero-GPL or a Commercial license. But there's an [older version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692000/can-i-use-a-previous-version-of-itextsharp-under-the-lgpl) under the LGPL.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [PDFBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pdf.php) package of our SecureBlackbox product? It supports PAdES and the sample for C# is included right in the installation package.

Comment: @Piercarlo then you got to write it yourself based on free stuff. afaik there are no other widely available implementations.

Answer (score 0):

[iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) is what are you looking for. It is the ported version of iText to C#, and as Filipe Correia answered, it have support to PADES.

The PADES standard have 5 parts.

iText (Java) and iTextSharp (C#), both:

- Have full support of PAdES Part 2
- Support of PAdES Part 3 with an external signature
- Have full support of PAdES Part 4
- And do not support PAdES Part 5.

This document could help : http://lowagie.com/img/summit2012/pades.pdf

If someone want more details about PADES, could look here : http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/102700_102799/10277801/01.01.01_60/ts_10277801v010101p.pdf